# How do I get which data is being grouped in AmChart pie

Tags: amcharts

I'm using a bar chart yo show what is selected in a pie chart. The pie chart has `"groupPercent": 5,` and I can't change this. **The problem is that, when I select te *"Other"* slice of the pie, it shows all the data in the bar chart.**

1. Can I show only what is included in *"Other"* slice?
2. Can I get this data in JSon type or something like that?

I think the solution is near the pullOutSlice listener:

```
chart.addListener("pullOutSlice", function (event) {
        if (event.dataItem.dataContext.data != undefined) {
            var skus = event.dataItem.dataContext.data;
```

Thanks!

Some code:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("resellersalespiechart", {
    "type": "pie",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "valueField": "qty",
    "titleField": "reseller",
    "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]",
    "pullOutOnlyOne": true,
    "groupPercent": 5,
    "groupedTitle": "Otros",
    "legend": {
        "position": "bottom",
        "marginRight": 20,
        "autoMargins": false
    }
});

// create column chart
var chart2 = AmCharts.makeChart("resellersalesbarchart", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "pathToImages": "/lib/3/images/",
    "autoMargins": false,
    "marginLeft": 30,
    "marginRight": 8,
    "marginTop": 10,
    "marginBottom": 26,
    "titles": [{
        "text": "Todos los resellers"
    }],
    "dataProvider": collectiveData,
    "startDuration": 1,
    "graphs": [{
        "title": "projects",
        "type": "column",
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "valueField": "qty",
        "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>"
    }],
    "categoryField": "sku",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "autoGridCount": false,
        "gridCount": 12,
        "labelFunction": function (valueText, serialDataItem, categoryAxis) {
            return valueText;
        },
        "fontSize": 9
    },
    "valueAxes": [{
        "integersOnly": true,
        "fontSize": 9,
        "labelFunction": function (value, valueText, valueAxis) {
            if (value >= 1000) {
                return (value / 1000) + "K";
            } else {
                return valueText;
            }
        }
    }]
});

chart.addListener("pullInSlice", function (event) {
        if (event.dataItem.dataContext.skus != undefined) {

            chart1BarData = collectiveData;
            chart1BarTitle = "Todos los resellers"

            chart2.dataProvider = collectiveData;
            chart2.titles[0].text = "Todos los resellers";
            chart2.validateData();
            chart2.animateAgain();
        }
    });
```

Chart example:
[Image of the different views of charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY4I8.png)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with a sample of your data? It's hard to visualize your problem.

Comment: That is what I can publish...

Comment: How about your data? At least provide some fake data that matches your format and also explains your problem - "The problem is that, when I select te "Other" slice of the pie, it shows all the data in the bar chart." This needs clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there isn't a direct way to do this. You'll need to loop through your dataProvider and aggregate the elements whose calculated percent value is under the groupPercent threshold then aggregate each element's sub array into a dataProvider array for your bar chart. For example:

```
    if (event.dataItem.dataContext.skus != undefined) {

        chart1BarData = collectiveData;
        chart1BarTitle = "Todos los resellers"

        chart2.dataProvider = collectiveData;
        chart2.titles[0].text = "Todos los resellers";
        chart2.validateData();
        chart2.animateAgain();
    }
    else {
        var sum = event.chart.chartData.reduce(function(accumulator, dataElement) {
          return accumulator + dataElement.value;
        }, 0);
        var groupedElements = [];
        event.chart.dataProvider.forEach(function(dataElement) {
          if ((dataElement[event.chart.valueField] / sum) * 100 < event.chart.groupPercent) {
            groupedElements.push(dataElement);
          }
        });
        //aggregate/build chart dataProvider and assign to  chart2 here
    }
```

Comment: I ended up in looping. :(